# iPhone Core Data - context

Tags: iphone, core-data

Suppose I create a new project with core data. A project with a root view controller.

By default, Apple adds a self.managedObjectContext reference to this main viewController.

Now I add other classes to my project.

At some point I will have to read the objects from the core data entities and I will have to access that managedObjectContext. How do you guys obtain that context from other classes?

I know I can import the rootViewController.h on the class I want to access the context, but I am trying to do that without importing the header on multiple classes, because I want to make the classes as much independent of each other as possible and because I think this is not a good solution as it will create a mess of cross references between classes. I may be wrong.

I now I can use:

```
managedObjectContext = [(MyAppDelegateName *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

but then I will have to import MyAppDelegateName.h and the problem is the same.

Is there a better way to do that?
How do you solve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce dependency on CoreData by wrapping either with Repository design pattern, or with just a high level Model that handles all Core Data interactions for you. Then either have the model as a statically available class, singleton it (not recommended), or pass it through your ViewControllers.

Edit:

Repository Pattern - define specific repositories for each of your data objects. For example, if you have Suppliers and Products, you would have 2 repository classes, and each Repository conforms to a set interface. As a illustrative example:

```
@protocol Repository{
    -(id)GetByKey:(NSInteger *)key;
    -(id)GetAll;

    -(id)RemoveByKey:(NSInteger *)key;
    -(id)RemoveAll;
}

@interface SupplierRepository:NSObject <Repository>
@end

@interface ProductRepository:NSObject <Repository>
@end
```

Your core data entities will also need to conform to some conventions, such as a surrogate key. I've never done this, so someone else may be able to better explain. Depending on your tolerance rating, you may decide to just instantiate repositories in your ViewControllers, or you may decide to just put it in a single Model instance anyway.

Comment: +1 for encapsulation of storage.  Create a model API which doesn't expose how you go about getting your objects.

Comment: Ok, I am tending to the second solution, I mean, passing it thru VC, but can you elaborate more on what you have said on your first phrase. Explain me as I was five. 

Comment: @DigitalRobot I added an example, however I do not have such a firm grasp on the pattern to confidently explain everything. :)

Comment: The more I look at this the more this doesn't seem right. It strikes me that Core Data is already a pretty solid implementation of the Repository pattern. It encapsulates collections of objects (in the managed object context), hides persistence details (the persistent store) and accepts queries using criteria (fetch requests and predicates). It seems wrong to treat Core Data as simply an ORM or data store as its not. It's an entire object graph manager. Adding a Repository layer seems redundant to me.

Comment: That's not to say that certain elements benefit from greater encapsulation, such as a having some convenient utilities that wrap simple queries, and strong encapsulation of more complex queries.

Comment: Exactly. The examples I used were pretty contrived, but you could also put something in like "getAllSuppliersWithMoreThanTenProducts" or something which would handle all the core-data interactions etc. for you.